# RoR v2.3 Model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I was wondering how I'm suppose to associate my `User, Post, and Comment` models. It is suppose to be like so: The user can comment on any post and a post belongs to a user with a Boolean for being admin. I have been scratching my had for awhile trying to figure this out but nothing has made any sense at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most obvious arrangement `Post` would `belong_to :user` and `has_many :comments`, and `Comment` would both `belong_to :user` and `belong_to :post`. `User` would `has_many :posts`.

Comment: but wouldn't User be like `has_many :posts` then Post `has_many :users`?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the following association in the model

```
# app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :comments
end
```